# Python encoding decoding how to

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am decoding a string "öçÇşŞükrÜ" to some other charset.

I encountered some interesting problem and want to learn how I can solve it.

```
>>> "öçÇşŞükrÜ".decode("utf-8")
u'\xf6\xe7\xc7\u015f\u015e\xfckr\xdc'
>>> "öçÇşŞükrÜ".decode("utf-8").encode("utf-8")
'\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa7\xc3\x87\xc5\x9f\xc5\x9e\xc3\xbckr\xc3\x9c'


>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect('\xc3\xb6\xc3\xa7\xc3\x87\xc5\x9f\xc5\x9e\xc3\xbckr\xc3\x9c')
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
>>> chardet.detect("öçÇşŞükrÜ")
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

What I do not understand and can not find is how to retrieve the original string "öçÇşŞükrÜ" with an decode and encode process with Python ?

Comment: Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Python files should be written in ASCII (although you can enter Unicode characters if you set the encoding).

Comment: Has been discussed many times before. Best resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am decoding a string "öçÇşŞükrÜ" to some other charset.

No, you're decoding an encoded string into an in-memory Unicode representation. Sorry if that sounds harsh, but IMHO it's *really* important to get the basics right with Unicode and not just fumble around until something works. **EDIT:** The resources in the comments, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html are also **essential**. Read and watch them. What you need to know is that **nothing on disk, or in your terminal is Unicode**. Everything is encoded, using one encoding or another.

If you are using Linux, you're lucky! (Us Windows devs... well, world of pain, etc.) Your console will most likely be UTF-8, so doing

```
"öçÇşŞükrÜ".decode("UTF-8")
```

will probably make sense.

Did you try

```
print "öçÇşŞükrÜ".decode("UTF-8").encode("UTF-8")
```

(that is, with `print` applied)? You should then get your original `öçÇşŞükrÜ` back.

Comment: Thanks, now I know I need to study more on encodings. That solved my problem.